# What is a good schema for a database where users can search for inventory availability on certain dates (such as Airbnb)?

Tags: database-design, schema, nosql, high-availability

I apologize if this is not the right venue to ask such a question. This is my first time on this site and I'm open to suggestions.

I am trying to find a good schema for a database that needs to record discrete timeslots of availability of a certain item (like an Airbnb room for example) and allows users to search for items that are available on a certain timeslot.

My current solution, on a NoSQL database, is to have a collection of items with certain parameters, of which one is an array of available timeslots.

Example `Item`:

```
Item 1
Name: Foo
Location: Miami
Available_Dates:
[Tues 10am, Tues 11am, Wed 12pm, Wed 1pm....]
```

From this schema, I would search for items where `available_dates` contain X or Y *slot(s)*.

Since the potential available times can be quite a few per item, I'm not sure if my current solution is the optimal one. Is there a best practice for something like this, or a suggestion as to how I could structure my database?

Comment: [Article on AirBnb's structure with MySQL, HDFS, etc](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/data-infrastructure-at-airbnb-8adfb34f169c)

Comment: You might want your site to be up a couple of months before envisaging an Airbnb type infrastructure ( :-) ) - so in the meantime, as you're getting off the ground, you might want to take a look at some of the schemas [here](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) (search for "reservation" and "booking"). p.s. @scsimon +1 - nice article.

Comment: Thanks.. updated my question to reflect that I'm more interested in the schema than the infrastructure